# All Monitors of the second GPU are disconnected. Ubuntu 18.04 - Nvidia 396.54

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I'm setting up a workstation with 2 GPU (Nvidia GTX1050 Ti) and 6 displays ([samsung md230x6](https://www.samsung.com/us/computer/monitors/LS23MURHB/ZA-specs)).

It's all working fine except that the desktop shows only on the displays of the first GPU; the other three are black: I cannot move any window upon but the mouse cursor actually shows as a black cross with white outline.

Funny fact is that I can actually change the color of the black screens via nvidia-settigs GUI Color Correction.

Seem the same issue as in [3rd monitor showing "X" cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843561/3rd-monitor-showing-x-cursor).

nvidia-smi:

```
$ nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.54                 Driver Version: 396.54                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   46C    P8    N/A / 120W |    624MiB /  4037MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 105...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 45%   29C    P0    N/A /  75W |     64MiB /  4040MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       953      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            34MiB |
|    0      1003      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          48MiB |
|    0      1250      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           286MiB |
|    0      1393      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         147MiB |
|    0      2355      G   ...-token=C398224CE3FA660C9FF3A88B97994567   105MiB |
|    1       953      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            30MiB |
|    1      1250      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            31MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

xrandr:

```
$ xrandr
 Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
 DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
    1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00  
    ...
 HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 DP-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 278mm
    1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
    ...
 DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
    1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00  
    ...
```

kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux myhostname 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
```

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

[/etc/X11/xorg.conf](https://gist.github.com/pliski/73a68ba3cd2b489a008e4c822db0c717)

[/var/log/Xorg.log](https://gist.github.com/pliski/b3ede6b301c16199e8ebd84f876fb8f2)

**Update:**

Turns out it is not possible to extend the desktop to the 6 monitors with the proprietary driver and two cards. Thanks to Generix for the [answers](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1039118/linux/-396-54-gtx1050ti-ubuntu-18-04-all-monitors-of-second-gpu-are-disconnected/).

So I'm trying with Nouveau but for now I'm stuck in the notorius login loop... [to be continued]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 2020 report

Rig update:

_ CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600

_ Mobo: AsRock X570 Phantom Gaming

_ GPU: Radeon RX Vega 56 with 6 HDMI output ports.

_ ...

OS:

with Ubuntu 18, 19 and 20 working like a charm out of the box.

(Funny thing: is not working anymore on windows .. but who cares?!)

PS: this post concludes the yearly reports, as the original issue is a past story, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

### 2019 report

A year later I had some time to spend in this issue and although I did not find a proper solution I found a workaround:

Rig update:

- [one external video card](https://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-N105TWF2OC-4GD#kf) with 4 monitors connected (3 hdmi and 1 dvi)
- and the Intel HD530 embedded in [my motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170-PRO-GAMING/) connected to the rest of the monitors (1 dvi and 1 vga).

OS update:

- ubuntu 19.04,
- kernel 5.0.0-20-generic,
- gnome 3.32.1,
- xserver-xorg-core | 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3 | amd64,
- nvidia driver 418.56.

It just worked out of the box after the Ubuntu installation.